# Jenkins Build Test Case pass fail count using groovy script

Tags: groovy, junit, jenkins, hudson

I want to fetch Total TestCase PASS and FAIL count for a build using groovy script. I am using Junit test results. I am using Multiconfiguration project , so is there any way to find this information on a per configuration basis?

Answer (score 5):

If you use the plugin https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin, you can access the Jenkins TestResultAction directly from the build ie.

```
import hudson.model.*

def build = manager.build

int total = build.getTestResultAction().getTotalCount()
int failed = build.getTestResultAction().getFailCount()
int skipped = build.getTestResultAction().getSkipCount()
// can also be accessed like build.testResultAction.failCount

manager.listener.logger.println('Total: ' + total)
manager.listener.logger.println('Failed: ' + failed)
manager.listener.logger.println('Skipped: ' + skipped)
manager.listener.logger.println('Passed: ' + (total - failed - skipped))
```

API for additional TestResultAction methods/properties http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/tasks/test/AbstractTestResultAction.html

If you want to access a matrix build from another job, you can do something like:

```
def job = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName('MyJobName/MyAxisName=MyAxisValue');
def build = job.getLastBuild()
...
```

Answer (score 2):

For Pipeline (Workflow) Job Type, the logic is slightly different from AlexS' answer that works for most other job types:

```
build.getActions(hudson.tasks.junit.TestResultAction).each {action ->
    action.getTotalCount()
    action.getFailCount()
    action.getSkipCount()
}
```

(See http://hudson-ci.org/javadoc/hudson/tasks/junit/TestResultAction.html)

[Pipeline](http://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/workflow-job/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/job/WorkflowRun.html) jobs don't have a getTestResultAction() method.

I use this logic to disambiguate:

```
if (build.respondsTo('getTestResultAction')) {
   //normal logic, see answer by AlexS     

} else {
   // pipeline logic above
}
```

Comment: in test report, i would like to also add error test cases as 4th category. Is it possible?

Comment: @limonik, Jenkins Junit plugin appears to bundle "error" and "failure" into one concept (though I could be wrong here), so I don't think that you can do that out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be able to do it with something like this:

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;

File fXmlFile = new File("junit-tests.xml");

DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

println("Total : " + doc.getDocumentElement().getAttribute("tests"))
println("Failed : " +doc.getDocumentElement().getAttribute("failures"))
println("Errors : " +doc.getDocumentElement().getAttribute("errors"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I also harvest junit xml test results and use Groovy post-build plugin https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin to check pass/fail/skip counts. Make sure the order of your post-build actions has harvest junit xml before the groovy post-build script.

This example script shows how to get test result, set build description with result counts and also version info from a VERSION.txt file AND how to change overall build result to UNSTABLE in case all tests were skipped.

```
def currentBuild = Thread.currentThread().executable
// must be run groovy post-build action AFTER harvest junit xml  
testResult1 = currentBuild.testResultAction

currentBuild.setDescription(currentBuild.getDescription() + "\n pass:"+testResult1.result.passCount.toString()+", fail:"+testResult1.result.failCount.toString()+", skip:"+testResult1.result.skipCount.toString())

// if no pass, no fail all skip then set result to unstable
if (testResult1.result.passCount == 0 && testResult1.result.failCount == 0 && testResult1.result.skipCount > 0) {
   currentBuild.result = hudson.model.Result.UNSTABLE
}

currentBuild.setDescription(currentBuild.getDescription() + "\n" + currentBuild.result.toString())

def ws = manager.build.workspace.getRemote()
myFile = new File(ws + "/VERSION.txt")
desc = myFile.readLines()
currentBuild.setDescription(currentBuild.getDescription() + "\n" + desc)
```